# Starting New Development with Mean Stack - should I use Angular 2.0?

Tags: angularjs

I am on a team that is starting a greenfield project and we are building our architecture on the MEAN stack.  I am aware that AngularJS 2.0 is emerging is a complete rewrite.  I have no issue with being aggressive if it is practical to do so as it will protect our software investment.  Is it practical to use 2.0 at this time or should we stick with 1.3?  Are there any MEAN - Angular examples available?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't make sense to go to Angular 2.0. It's nowhere close to production use yet. Moreover, I would question your desire to use MEAN. http://developer.olery.com/blog/goodbye-mongodb-hello-postgresql/

As this post and numerous others like it show, MongoDB isn't necessarily THE database for your app. It's a good supporting database in which you store data you don't mind losing. https://aphyr.com/posts/284-call-me-maybe-mongodb. This post is based on the 2.x branch and Mongo 3.x has been released. However, it hasn't proven that it's vanquished all its data-losing ways.

Seriously think carefully about standardasing yourself on such a data store. There's much to say about NodeJS, but I will reserve that for now.

Answer (score 0):

1.3 is probably best for a production app at this time

[github examples](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=angular%20%24scope%20mongo%20express&type=Code&ref=searchresults)

[An app generator](http://meanjs.org/generator.html)

[Possible Hint of 2.0 release](http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/03/angular-2-concerns-addressed)